# How to get native (root) ZFS on ubuntu 23?

Tags: zfs, 23.04

[image: ubuntu install process step 5]

[image: ubuntu install process step 5 experimental features use ZFS]

I love ZFS. it should never have been removed. I stuck with 21.04 until I couldn't take it anymore just because of that.

how do I get ZFS on ubuntu 23 again?

Answer (score 1):

when downloading ubuntu don't click this :

[image: download normal]

click this instead :

[image: download legacy]